# Do TypeScript interfaces not limit the amount of properties?

Tags: typescript

This is an example from Codecademy:

```
interface Code {
   [code: string]: number;
}
const stateToNumbers: Code = {'NH': 603, 'MA': 617};
```

Neither Codecademy or the TypeScript documentation seem to say how this is possible. Are we supposed to assume that a property defined in an interface doesn't have to do with the amount allowed to be declared, even though that isn't the case for type aliases?

Comment: It's worth noting that in the example you gave you should probably account for keys not being defined `[code: string]: number | undefined`. Otherwise typescript will treat any key as if it exists and won't save you if you do something like this: `stateToNumbers.anything.toFixed()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither Codecademy or the TypeScript documentation say how this is possible.

The TypeScript documentation does, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

> **Index Signatures**
>
> Sometimes you don’t know all the names of a type’s properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values.
>
> In those cases you can use an index signature to describe the types of possible values, for example:
>
> ```typescript
> interface StringArray {
>   [index: number]: string;
> }
>
> const myArray: StringArray = getStringArray();
> const secondItem = myArray[1];
> ```
>
> ...
>
> An index signature property type must be either ‘string’ or ‘number’.
>
> ...
>
> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type. This is because a string index declares that obj.property is also available as obj["property"]. In the following example, name’s type does not match the string index’s type, and the type checker gives an error:
>
> ```typescript
> interface NumberDictionary {
>   [index: string]: number;
>
>   length: number; // ok
>   name: string; // Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'number'.
> }
> ```

Basically, your `Code` interface says that instances can have properties with any string name, but their values must be numbers.

Aside from the above, in reference to your question title:

> Do TypeScript interfaces not limit the amount of properties?

They don't, **except** when you're doing an object literal. For instance, this is perfectly valid:

```typescript
interface JustA {
    a: string;
}

let something = {
    a: "ayy",
    b: "bee",
};

let x: JustA = something;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIFcDOYCCyDeAUMicnAFzLZSgDmA3IQL6GEA2EYVA9gLacALOsgC8BYqQrIARHACec6QBoJJAEaVpaiBGXNG7TsgAelDNjxjMfQXXpA)

But this is not:

```typescript
interface JustA {
    a: string;
}

let x: JustA = {
    a: "ayy",
    b: "bee", // Error
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIFcDOYCCyDeAUMicnAFzLZSgDmA3IQL6GEA2EYyAHpRtngC8BYqQrIARHACe0iQBpRJAEaUJyiBAXIA9DuQBRKFAD2UZvSA)

That's because TypeScript only does [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)¹ on object literals. Other than that, it's valid to assign a subtype instance (an object with more properties) to a supertype variable.

---

¹ *(that page says it's obsolete, but the new page doesn't cover them yet)*

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of an “index signature” in typescript. See here for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures

Basically, the bracket syntax there says that this object can have as many properties as you want, as long as the index is a string and the value is a number. `code` in that example is just an arbitrary name for the index to help understand it’s purpose.